# how to ungroup css selector using macOS sed or awk or grep or gsub?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, gsub

file has:

```
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA,.class2,.class3,.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
.classA,.classB .class1{color:blue}
```

expected:

```
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class2{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class3{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
.classA{color:blue}
.classB .class1{color:blue}
```

How to ungroup?

```
awk '{count=gsub(/,\./, ",."); if ($0 ~ /,./) for(i=0;i<=count;i++) print $0; if ($0 !~ /,./) print $0 }'
```

gives:

```
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA,.class2,.class3,.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA,.class2,.class3,.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA,.class2,.class3,.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA,.class2,.class3,.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
.classA,.classB .class1{color:blue}
.classA,.classB .class1{color:blue}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution(GNU `awk`):*** With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. This code validates the number of opening and closing `{` and `}` but again it checks only number of them and its not intelligent to tell you that its a valid CSS or not that a css parser could only do.

```bash
awk '
gsub(/{/,"&")==1 && gsub(/}/,"&")==1 && match($0,/(^[^{]*){(.*)}$/,arr1){
  num=split(arr1[1],arr2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     print arr2[i]"{"arr1[2]"}"
  }
  next
}
gsub(/{/,"&")==gsub(/}/,"&") && gsub(/{/,"&")>1 && match($0,/(^.*){(.*)}}$/,arr3){
  split(arr3[1],arr4,"{")
  num1=split(arr4[2],arr5,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
     print arr4[1]"{"arr5[i]"{"arr3[2]"}}"
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** This should work in any POSIX `awk`. Written and tested with shown samples Only.

```bash
awk '
gsub(/{/,"&")==1 && gsub(/}/,"&")==1{
  split($0,arr1,"[}{]")
  num1=split(arr1[1],arr2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
     print arr2[i]"{"arr1[2]"}"
  }
  next
}
gsub(/{/,"&")==gsub(/}/,"&") && gsub(/{/,"&")>1{
   num2=split($0,arr3,"{")
   num3=split(arr3[2],arr4,",")
   for(i=1;i<=num3;i++){
     print arr3[1]"{"arr4[i]"{"arr3[num2]
   }
}
'  Input_file
```

With your shown samples output will be as follows:

```
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class1 .classA{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class2{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class3{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@xyz, xyz, (z){.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
.classA{color:blue}
.classB .class1{color:blue}
```

Comment: need suggestion how to make it work in macOS.

Comment: @SharadShrestha, Since you are in mac can you please try like: `sudo port install gawk` once and then check if you got gawk in your system?

Comment: @SharadShrestha, I just googled and got this link https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gawk to install it in MAC, I don't have MAC so can't test it, try it out once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: thank u. I am trying to solve this with awk macOS without gawk.

Comment: @SharadShrestha, Ok, let me write it without GNU `awk`, give me few mins or so and will get back here.

Comment: @SharadShrestha, Could you please try my 2nd solution once and let me know if that help you, should be Ok I believe.

Comment: @SharadShrestha, Did it work out for you?

Comment: awesome it did work.

Comment: how to handle such css selector as well:

media only screen and (max-width: 1068px){.class1 .class2{justify-content:flex-start}.class3{justify-content:flex-end}.class4 .class5{justify-content:center}.class6{justify-content:space-between}}

expected:

media only screen and (max-width: 1068px){.class1 .class2{justify-content:flex-start}}
media only screen and (max-width: 1068px){.class4 .class5{justify-content:center}}
media only screen and (max-width: 1068px){.class6{justify-content:space-between}}

Comment: @SharadShrestha. in my humble opinion, you could accept this answer and then open a new question with new samples and your tried code and we can discuss there. Editing question after sometime is not encouraged as it will confuse users, kindly do let me know on same cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578869/how-to-ungroup-css-selector-using-macos-awk-posix