# how to ungroup css selector using macOS awk (POSIX)

Tags: awk, sed, gsub

File input.txt has following:

```
.classA,.classB .class1{color:blue}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA,.class2,.class3,.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{margin-right:0}.class1 .classB{margin-right:2%}.class2 .classC{margin-right:2}}
```

Expected result:

```
.classA{color:blue}
.classB .class1{color:blue}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class2{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class3{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{margin-right:0}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classB{margin-right:2%}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class2 .classC{margin-right:2}}
```

How to ungroup css selectors?

```
awk '
gsub(/{/,"&")==1 && gsub(/}/,"&")==1{
  split($0,arr1,"[}{]")
  num1=split(arr1[1],arr2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
     print arr2[i]"{"arr1[2]"}"
  }
  next
}
gsub(/{/,"&")==gsub(/}/,"&") && gsub(/{/,"&")>1{
   num2=split($0,arr3,"{")
   num3=split(arr3[2],arr4,",")
   for(i=1;i<=num3;i++){
     print arr3[1]"{"arr4[i]"{"arr3[num2]
   }
}
' input.txt
```

It gives following result which is not expected:

```
.classA{color:blue}
.classB .class1{color:blue}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class2{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class3{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{margin-right:2}}
```

How to solve this using macOS awk (POSIX)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like setting `FS` to split on `{` and `}` should work fine as long as each definition is in a single line:

```bash
awk -F '[{}]' '
    NF == 3 {
        n = split($1,arr,",")
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            print arr[i] "{" $2 "}"
        next
    }
    NF > 3 {
        for (f = 2; f < NF-2; f += 2) { 
            n = split($f,arr,",")
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                print $1 "{" arr[i] "{" $(f+1) "}}"
        }
        next
    }
'
```

```css
.classA{color:blue}
.classB .class1{color:blue}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class2{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class3{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class4 .classB{background-image:url("1.png")}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classA{margin-right:0}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class1 .classB{margin-right:2%}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){.class2 .classC{margin-right:2}}
```

Comment: thank u but this does not give expected result.